# Rotation a view from Landscape to Portrait

Tags: ios, uiview, rotation

I have a view A and a view controller B, when View A exit (device in Landscape, view A overlay on B), I want to transform B to Portrait(device keep in Landscape, so B should be in Landscape before transform, but I have fixed the frame of B, so If B show up in Landscape, a part of screen should dark and no-responsible). But I get a un-responsible black area in the bottom of screen. The View B show itself in a smaller window in this screen and I can scroll it. My transform code as:

```
    CGFloat r = 1.5 * M_PI;
    CGAffineTransform t;
    t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( r );
    UIApplication *application = [ UIApplication sharedApplication ];
   self.view.frame = frame;
   self.view.center = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + ceil(frame.size.width/2), frame.origin.y + ceil(frame.size.height/2));
self.view.bounds = [[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ];
    t = CGAffineTransformTranslate(t, 130, 105);
    [self.view setTransform:t];

    [ application setStatusBarOrientation: UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated: YES ];
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is a bit odd, i guess it's not a copy/paste from your code source:
you initialize t with a double whereas its a CGAffineTransform
r is not declared
frame is not declared

for your problem, different points:
don't use frame property of UIView if a transformation is applied on that view
bounds of UIScreen contains the 20 points height of statusBar, use applicationFrame method of UIScreen instead
Why do you set the center and then applied a translation ?

If your viewController is your rootViewController (so that its view is a direct subview of the window) you could maybe try something like:

```
[self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
[self.view setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
[self.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
```

if your viewController is not your rootViewController, you have to set a rotation indeed but center depends on superview bounds

Comment: This viewController is not the rootViewController. How can I get the superview's bounds ? thank you !